# How to fix an "Access to the path csproj.nuget.g.props is denied" error in Azure DevOps build with Docker Build?

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm setting up a buid in Azure DevOps with a Docker Image and have some problems. My docker build command doesn't work in local and in Azure DevOps build machine.
In local the command throws this error :

```powershell
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.401\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\app\src\WebApi\WebApi.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.401\NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   No such host is known [C:\app\src\WebApi\WebApi.csproj]
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore src/WebApi/WebApi.csproj' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

And in Azure DevOps this error :

```powershell
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.401\NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Access to the path 'C:\app\src\Bll\obj\Bll.csproj.nuget.g.props' is denied. [C:\app\src\WebApi\WebApi.csproj]
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore src/WebApi/WebApi.csproj' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]The process 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to restart the Docker service and turn off automatic windows proxy configuration. The problem was on my local machine, it was not able to reach the url. So, I tried to build my dockerfile in Azure DevOps. And I don't understand why the restore step fails too with permission error.
I searched for solutions on Google, but didn't find any.

My dockerfile :

```
# STAGE01 - Build application and its dependencies
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY src/**/*.csproj ./
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore .\Authentication.sln

# STAGE02 - Publish the application
FROM build-env AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

# STAGE03 - Create the final image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2.0-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
LABEL Author="Tango"
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll", "--server.urls", "http://*:80"]
```

Solution folder structure:

> ```
>  .sln
>  dockerfile
>  src /
>  -- Dal /
>  ---- Dal.csproj
>  -- Bll /
>  ---- Bll.csproj
>  -- WebApi /
>  ---- WebApi.csproj
> ```

What am I missing?

Comment: The `obj` folder should not add into the source control, it will generated at building. Try to delete it in your repos.

Comment: obj was ignored by git, there were no bin and obj in my repo. But, i found app folder in my repo ! I removed it, and now it works well ! thank's.

Comment: I believe we need to add the .dockerignore file for ```bin``` and ```obj``` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App folder was tracked in my git repo, i removed it. It works.